# golang で受け取った可変長引数を他の可変長引数に渡したい

Tags: go

Go の初心者です。

Golang で、正しく動いている次のコードがあります。

```
package main

import "os/exec"
import fmt "fmt"

func main() {

     c, _ := exec.Command("git", "log", "--first-parent", "--merges").Output()
     s := string(c[:])
     fmt.Printf(s)
}
```

---

これの、コマンド実行部分を関数に切り出そうとして、次のように変更を行いました。

```
package main

import "os/exec"
import fmt "fmt"

func executeCommand(command ...string) string {
     c, _ := exec.Command(command...).Output()
     return string(c[:])
}

func main() {

     s := executeCommand("git", "log", "--first-parent", "--merges")
     fmt.Printf(s)
}
```

すると、次のエラーが発生します。

```
# command-line-arguments
./calc.go:7:27: error: argument 1 has incompatible type
      c, _ := exec.Command(command...).Output()
                           ^
./calc.go:7: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

`command...` で、受け取った配列を展開して、 `exec.Command()` に引き渡せるものだと思っていたのですが、上記の通りそうはなっていないです。

---

質問:

- 私は、何を間違えているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージにあるとおりです。 `exec.Command` は第1引数は `string` なので、スライスではなく `string` を渡す必要があります。

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command

```
package main


import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func executeCommand(command ...string) string {
    c, _ := exec.Command(command[0], command[1:]...).Output()
    return string(c[:])
}

func main() {
    s := executeCommand("git", "log", "--first-parent", "--merges")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

本題からは外れるのですが、`exec.Command()` の signature が

```golang
func Command(name string, arg ...string)
```

となっていますので、`executeCommand()` もこれに合わせる方が良いかと思います。

可変長引数だけにすると引数がない場合でも compile error にならずに `executeCommand()` が実行されてしまい、その結果 runtime error が発生してしまいます。

```golang
s := executeCommand()

panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
```

どうしても可変長引数だけにしたい場合は可変長引数(`command`)の length check などをしておくべきかと思います。